# How to display branch name in github action list

Tags: github, github-actions

i'm looking for a tip to display branch name in github action list like the following screen shot.

[image]

As you can see, sometimes github automaticly add the branch name and i would to know if it's possible to configure something to display the branch name everytime.

Anyone to help me ?
Thanks